# Wrong double value when trying to get it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC web application. In one of my view, I've got a listbox which is filled by some double value (base on my ViewModel) :

```
public class SuggestionViewModel
{
    public bool PADP { get; set; }
    public bool PremedicationPADP { get; set; }
    public double NbPADP { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PADPItems { get; set; }
    public bool Other { get; set; }

    public SuggestionViewModel()
    {
        PADPItems = (new double[] { 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4 }).Select(d => new SelectListItem { Value = d.ToString(), Text = d.ToString() });

        PADCItems = (new double[] { 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4 }).Select(d => new SelectListItem { Value = d.ToString(), Text = d.ToString() });
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to recover these values through an action in my controller, I've got some wrong values. For instance, if I choose in my View '0.25', I'll get '25.0' which if totally false. Why does the value change when I try to get it?

EDIT : The listbox HTML code I get :

```
<option value ="0,25">0,25</option>
<option value ="0,5">0,50</option>
<option value ="0,75">0,75</option>
<option value ="1">1</option>
```

Comment: Please paste the HTML markup that you get and the code from your view also

Comment: It's probably a localization issue. Try setting the localization of the browser to "English US". You're probably using a localization that has a different decimal separator than `.`.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers. I pasted my HTML code so you can see what I get. I also think that it is a localiation issue but I have to work with a french localization.

Comment: Well, that's always a hustle... **If** you know you're always going to use the French localization, you can use strings instead of doubles and parse the strings using your target localization.

Comment: @AndreiV thank you, it works! I didn't think about that... Could you please post the solution as an answer that I could accept? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the "right thing to do" is to set the localization of your entire solution to French (based on the comments, this is what you use). However, this usually introduces overhead and influence other settings, such as configuration settings of external components (e.g. jQueryUI, Kendo -- think about dates). A different solution would be to change the type of the model from `double` to `string` and, in your controller, to parse it using your targeted localization.

```
public class SuggestionViewModel
{
    public bool PADP { get; set; }
    public bool PremedicationPADP { get; set; }
    public string NbPADP { get; set; } //*1
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PADPItems { get; set; }
    public bool Other { get; set; }

    public SuggestionViewModel()
    {
         PADPItems = (new double[] { 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4 }).Select(d => new SelectListItem { Value = d.ToString(), Text = d.ToString() });

         PADCItems = (new double[] { 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4 }).Select(d => new SelectListItem { Value = d.ToString(), Text = d.ToString() });
    }
}
```

I assume that you get your selected value in the `NbPADP` property (correct me if I'm wrong). When you use your model, you can get the double value by converting it using the French localization:

```
 double dNbPADP = Double.Parse(model.NbPADP, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```